# Resizing control to the actual height and width not working correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working with 3rd party application, that draws a 3D models using unity.
I'm suppose to send the `height`, `width`, and `position` to the library, and it will display a 3D design depending on the values I have send.

The image below shows where the view is supposed to render, the purple area with red border.
[image: The view sould render at the purple area]
as you can see at the right bottom corner, I have printed the actual height and width for both the user control and the border inside using this code:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding ActualHeight, StringFormat={}{0}: height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding ActualHeight, StringFormat={}{0}: border height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" />
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding ActualWidth, StringFormat={}{0}: width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding ActualWidth, StringFormat={}{0}: border width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" />
</DockPanel>
```

and I got the same result when getting the actual height and width from code behind to send them to the library:

```
Point position = Application.Current.MainWindow.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
var pointToScreen = PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
pointToScreen.X -= position.X;
pointToScreen.Y -= position.Y;

var actualHeight = this.ActualHeight;
var actualWidth = this.ActualWidth;
var actualBorderHeight = renderBorder.ActualHeight;
var actualBorderWidth = renderBorder.ActualWidth;
```

And I got the same results when checking the area using Snoop
[image]

as you can see the results is **643 for height and 1470 for width**.

but the rendered view is always smaller, than the actual area. so I took a screenshot and using paint application, I got **height is 772 and the width is 1763**. so I send those values exactly as I got them from paint, and the view got rendered exactly as I wanted.

[image]

So what exactly is happening? and how I'm suppose to get the correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look's like you have issues with Windows UI DPI scaling.
You can get windows scale by this properties:

```
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow);
double scaleX, scaleY;
if (source != null) {
    scaleX = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
    scaleY = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
}
```

`scaleX` and `scaleY` will contain multipiler's for your width and height.

```
var actualHeight = this.ActualHeight * scaleY;
var actualWidth = this.ActualWidth * scaleX;
var actualBorderHeight = renderBorder.ActualHeight * scaleY;
var actualBorderWidth = renderBorder.ActualWidth * scaleX;
```

Answer (score 1):

Though that @Mikolaytis answer is working, I found a simpler solution using [GetDpi()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getdpi%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method,

```
var dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this);
var height = this.ActualHeight * dpiScale.DpiScaleY;
var width = this.ActualWidth * dpiScale.DpiScaleX;
```